# PCB Antenna Tuning

Tags: pcb, antenna, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna

[image: PCB Antenna]

I am trying to tune an antenna as seen above, using this wonderful [Smith Chart Tool](https://www.will-kelsey.com/smith_chart/). It needs to match 35 + 10j characteristic impedance.

I have found a tool like the [Microstrip Impedance Calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/microstrip-impedance) to determine the impedance of the transmission lines.

However, i am unsure how to determine the characteristic impedance of the stubs that don't have a ground plane (green area) behind them. Does anyone know how that impedance is calculated?

Comment: I heard on another forum that my notion of what a stub is, may have been incorrect. I presumed that the antenna could be modeled with stubs, but in fact, stubs are a different thing, used to tune the antenna. Does the antenna etching itself maybe have zero theoretical impedance when modeling with the link included?

Answer (score 1):

Given stubs over air, with unknown parasitics and RF return paths(unknown phase shifts), your tuning task becomes cut_and_try.

Stub tuning tends to be predicted, with AIR above and a KNOWN dielectric spaced a KNOWN distance above an smooth (uncut, no slits, no nearly Vias) GROUND plane.

Comment: I don't know anything about antennas but how come the stubs being over air suddenly makes everything unknown? Free space or something around the stub can't be used in the calculations?

Comment: Most of the PCB trace antennas I have looked at explicitly say not to have the ground under the stubs lines. The Smith Chart Tool I linked seems to think there's a way to calculate the open and short stub impedances, but I haven't found any examples off the net for that.

Comment: Normal stub matching is based on starting from high (or 0) impedance and then rotating it around the Smith chart edge until you reach the parallel capacitance or inductance you need for the matching. 

The stub without a ground plane cannot support a TEM wave and so it won’t work as a transmission line in the usual sense. So you cannot model the impedance just with the normal transmission line equations or with smith chart.